# where does lspci gather its information from?

Tags: proc, documentation

In [kernel.org's documentation on `proc`](https://www.kernel.org/doc//Documentation/filesystems/proc.txt) I found "[*The   latest   version    of   this   document   [is    available   online](http://tldp.org/LDP/Linux-Filesystem-Hierarchy/html/proc.html)*". There I says: "… `lspci` *is a synonym for* `cat /proc/pci`".

Which isn't the case here, on a Crunchbang 10 system (Debian based). No such directory. I do get the basic idea and, as far as I  know, the content of `proc` is (mainly) created during runtime. (Wrong?). This made me curious:

**Question**: Where does `lspci` gather it's information from? And where is this documented? (Where did I miss something?)

Another difference I found: In kernel.org's documentation, under "*Table 1-5: Kernel info in* `/proc`"

> `pci`     Deprecated info of PCI bus (new way -> `/proc/bus/pci/`, decoupled by `lspci)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`lspci` is part of pciutils, which is portable to a variety of unix-like OS's *and* windows, so it presumably uses different methods depending on platform.

You should be able to tell where it gets its info from in your case via `strace lspci`.  After the preamble accessing libraries, etc, I (using fedora linux) get a lot of `open()` + `pread()` calls on stuff in `/sys/bus/pci/`, e.g.:

```
open("/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1c.7/config", O_RDONLY) = 3
pread(3, "\206\200\36\36\7\0\20\0\304\0\4\6\20\0\201\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\7\7\0\360\0\0
\0"..., 64, 0) = 64
close(3)
```

That's binary data.  After this it reads in `/usr/share/hwdata/pci.ids`, which is a static universal list distributed with the pciutils package.  These are four digit codes which presumably correspond to the info from `/sys`.

Comment: `strace` is new to me, wasn't intalled but is awsome - thanks a lot. While I must get used to, well, use `strace - can you recommend a comparable way or tool to trace what a command actually does?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean -- as in, if `strace` is unavailable?  It won't tell you everything that's happening, just about the system calls.  To get more detail than that I think you'd need to run the command in a debugger.  Eg. the `strace` on `lspci` doesn't show how the stuff from `pci.ids` is made to correspond with the stuff read from `/sys`, because that wouldn't require any system calls.  To figure that out exactly, you'd need to peruse the source (possibly using a debugger too).

Comment: At the moment I'm quite  satisfied with `strace` - which I had to install, but yes: Is there something comparable in, say `coreutils` or so? The idea about using a debugger is great - something I will do in the future; e.g. following `lspci`'s `man`page I took a look into `/usr/include/linux/pci.h` - revealing and challenging… I was/am asking for, say: "Is there something like `which`for commands, in terms of: "show what a command actually does? Like in the documentation above, resolving "*command A actually is command B*" (and I know what an alias is :) )? Thanks a lot anyway!

Comment: No, there's nothing like that.  In this case, command A *actually is* command A.  The issue WRT that documentation is that it's perhaps inaccurate/outdated ("lspci is a synonym for cat whatever" is **at best an analogy** -- lspci certainly isn't literally a synonym, but what it does may resemble "cat whatever").  Much of the TLDP's link seems to be from `man proc`, BTW, which probably stands a better chance of remaining current/matching your system.

Comment: @chirp - there are 2 other tools related to `strace`. `ltrace` and `ptrace` that you might want to investigate. Also you can use the GNU debugger to attach to running processes too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14370972/how-to-attach-a-process-in-gdb

Answer (score 3):

#### /proc

I believe it was moved to `/proc/bus/pci`, so that all the buses could be kept in a single spot.

```
$ pwd
/proc/bus/pci
```

#### Example

`lspci` output:

```
$ lspci | tail -10
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000
0d:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd Device e822 (rev 01)
0d:00.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd Device e230 (rev 01)
0d:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd Device e832 (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 02)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 02)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 02)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 02)
```

Corresponding tree under `/proc/bus/pci`:

```
$ tree . | tail -10
|-- devices
`-- ff
    |-- 00.0
    |-- 00.1
    |-- 02.0
    |-- 02.1
    |-- 02.2
    `-- 02.3
```

#### /sys

The other location where device data is kept is under `/sys`. If you poke around there you'll notice this directory:

```
$ ls -l /sys/bus/pci
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root    0 Dec  1 09:43 devices
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root    0 Nov 30 16:27 drivers
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Dec  1 10:59 drivers_autoprobe
--w-------  1 root root 4096 Dec  1 10:59 drivers_probe
--w--w----  1 root root 4096 Dec  1 10:59 rescan
-rw-r--r--  1 root root 4096 Dec  1 10:59 resource_alignment
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root    0 Dec  1 10:36 slots
--w-------  1 root root 4096 Nov 30 16:27 uevent
```